# Current user variable in ListView class

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I want to execute a database query using the currently logged in user within a ListView class. Then after that I want to put those results into the extra_context variable so I can access them on the html page. After looking on different websites I found this piece of code:

```
class className(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
context_object_name = 'contextName'
template_name = 'app_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Userproject.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

How can I put the current user into a variable, that I can use later on in a database query so I can use it like this (I **dont** want to use the current user variable in the HTML. I **want** to access that variable within the class itself):

```
class className(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    user = THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE CURRENT USER VALUE
    context = {
        'friends': friends.Objects.filter(friendId = user.id)
    }

    model = User
    template_name = friends/friend.html
    context_object_name = 'friends'
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the DB query to your HTML page? Is that it?

Comment: What do you mean by How can I put the current user into a variable, that I can use later on in a database query??

Comment: I've added a piece of code as how I want it to be. I want to use the user variable within the database query - "friendId = user.id".

Answer (score 0):

you can override the get context data method.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ClassName, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user_obj'] = Userproject.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return context
```

you can avail user_obj in templates